# Swift code crash on string equals comparison

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I have following if condition in my code at line 155 as reported in crash snapshot posted in the end:

`if userId == UserService.sharedInstance()?.getUserId()`

`userId` on LHS is `9665c0d6-d444-4144-83fa-968eecc988d6`
and
`SharedInstance is <UserModule.UserService: 0x28212d5c0>` and `userId` on RHS is `c2d6a539-bb8b-4099-8229-2205feed65bd`

Strangely none of it is null or empty or deallocated as it is getting printed properly in logs just the line before it.

[image: Crash snapshot]

Edit 1: By "it is getting printed properly" I mean that all the values of `userId`, `UserService.sharedInstance()` and `UserService.sharedInstance()?.getUserId()` are getting properly printed in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

This error likely indicates that one of those objects has been over-released. It looks like you're working with ObjC objects, and I expect that there is a memory-management bug, probably on the ObjC side, but possibly in an Unsafe operation in Swift.

My first suspicion would be the one returned by `getUserId()`, but it could be the one returned by `sharedInstance()`.

It is also possible to get this kind of problem if you access objects from multiple-threads in invalid ways. (Though that's a little less common for this specific crash.)

It's unclear what you mean by "it" when you say "it is getting printed properly." If that includes the result of `getUserId()`, and this happens rarely, then I would be more suspicious of a threading bug, because that suggests a tight race condition.

Comment: By "it is getting printed properly" I mean that all the values of userId, UserService.sharedInstance() and UserService.sharedInstance()?.getUserId() are getting properly printed in the logs.

Comment: If that happens in precisely the line before this, then either you have a race condition due to multi-threading, or you've overridden `==` and touch memory there (I would much more suspect the former, though). Or you're misreading your logs. Or the "line 155" isn't the correct line. Or the logging function has a bug that over-releases the object (that would be weird). One way or another, you're trying to access an ObjC object that's been over-released. Something you assume is true about this code is not true, and the goal is to figure out what that thing is.

Comment: I found problems when you declare an Objective-C method as returning a non-null object, and then it returns nil. I’d try asserting that the return value is not nil (inside the method). And I find it easier if methods like sharedInstance can never return nil, and by making them class properties you can get rid of the parantheses.